# Hacer algo al validar todos los input usando evento blur

Tags: javascript

es algo básico nunca me había topado con esto, tengo varios `input` que estoy validando a través de `blur` es decir cuando pierde el focus reviso y hago cierta acción, el problema acá es que deseo saber cuando todos mis `input` estén validados.... tengo una estructura como esta;

```
const getId = id => document.getElementById(id);

  getId('primero')
    .addEventListener('blur', function(){
      if(this.value.length < 5){
        // fail
      }else{
        // valido
     }
   });

  getId('segundo')
    .addEventListener('blur', function(){
      if(this.value.length > 35){
        // fail
      }else{
        // valido
     }
   });
```

ahora bien, como saber cuando mis dos `input` estén validos y así poder hacer una acción. Busque varios ejemplos pero no me quedo claro realmente como poder hacerlo, agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Crea una única función para validar todos los controles:

```
function validate() {
    if (getId('primero').value.length < 5) {
        console.log('validación incorrecta');
        return false;
    }
    if (getId('segundo').value.length > 35) {
        console.log('validación incorrecta');
        return false;
    }

    console.log('todo perfecto');
    // Aquí puedes añadir la acción que requieras
    return true;
}
```

Luego enlazas esa función en todos los controles afectados:

```
getId('primero').addEventListener('blur', validate);
getId('segundo').addEventListener('blur', validate);
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, estoy teniendo el problema siguiente, y es que hasta que no se valida primero el segundo no hace la acción, es decir, primero tiene que ser true para darle paso a segundo, escribí el código tal cual, no entiendo el por que.

Comment: No te entiendo, pensaba que lo que querías era saber cuándo eran válidos los dos inputs y luego hacer algo más, que daba igual el orden

Comment: si, es exactamente lo que quiero pero a ver, ambos eventos estan con `blur` cuando quito el focus en el segundo antes del primero, curiosamente se activa lo que puse en el if del primero, me entiendes?

Comment: No mucho, lo siento. A ver, según lo que te he puesto, cuando pierde el foco cualquiera de los dos inputs se lanza la función validate, que comprueba los valores de ambos métodos. Es decir, entras en el primer control y escribes algo que tenga al menos 5 caracteres. Cuando cambias al segundo control, se lanza la función que ya pasa como correcta porque se cumplen ambas condiciones

Comment: si es correcto, el problema pasa cuando el usuario hace focus en el segundo input ANTES del primero, cuando levanta el focus de ese segundo se activa la funcion que deseo para el primero , ahora si me comprendes?